# Separate srcdir and objdir with vim and gcc

Tags: vim, gcc, makefile

When I'm working in vim, my current working directory (./) contains all my source. I build in an objdir, let's call it `./builddir/`. When I build from vim, using `makeprg=make\ -C\ builddir`, the compiler warnings and errors all have a prefix of `../`, which means vim brings the cursor to a file which doesn't exist.

If I try a different tactic, launching vim from the objdir, then I can't do commands like `gf` or `:e myfile.h` simply.

Is there a middle ground where all of this will work, like giving vim a second directory to search from if it can't find files in the current working directory? Or maybe getting gcc to use a different prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution would be to filter make outputs with sed to replace the output pathnames. (I've implemented a very similar thing to convert cygwin pathnames into windows pathnames for the win32 flavour of vim).

Something like:

```
:let &makeprg .= '2>&1 | sed "s#^\.\./##g"'
```

(It may be `\|` and not `|`, I don't remember)

Comment: I can't make this work at all. I've verified my command line works outside of vim, but I can't make the escaping work, not setting makeprg directly, nor using the let statement you have.

Comment: Ok, I got this working by making the command a bash script, and calling it via makeprg. Another fail for vim.

Comment: Actually, using a bash script is a bad idea - it buffers the input too much, which is not useful in this case. But I did figure the syntax out: `let &makeprg .= " -C build_\`hg qtop\`_DBG.OBJ 2>&1 \\\| sed 's,\\.\\./,,g'"` (and I've checked all my escaping - it appears correctly).

Comment: Oh. You use the double-quote characters instead of the single one. It complexifies the syntax (as in bash). (I did write a plugin aimed at filtering :make output hence I never remember the exact syntax now.)